# Can my tooltips be adapted for touch screen?

Tags: html, css

I've worked on the tool tips for my adverts which bust jargon quite a lot - they show with a simple mouse over. Obviously they don't work on touch interfaces.

I'm limited to ideally pure HTML5 and CSS3, definitely no jquery, ideally no javascript. I've tried changing (or rather adding) :active to the :hover class but nothing happens on a touch screen at all.

Current HTML and CSS is

```css
.tiptext {
  cursor: help;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33, .66, .66, 1);
  transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33, .66, .66, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 172%;
  -webkit-animation-name: link-helpoff;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: link-helpoff;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.tiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}
.tiptext:hover::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.description {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 275px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(39, 44, 45);
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tiptext > .description {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s linear;
}
.tiptext:hover > .description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
.tiptext:hover {
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation-name: link-help;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: link-help;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<span class="tiptext">
  <span class="description" style="text-align:center;">You can read more about the topic in this pop up box</span>
  Mouse over me to learn more.
</span>
```

There some animations and trickery going on in the CSS (and I haven't included the link-help animation but you get the idea) basically the box fades in and out when you mouse over it - and there is also a full screen white background that fades in with a little opaque to bring the moused over box into focus - its no big deal if this doesn't happen on touch screen devices.

I suspect there might need to be substantial changes to get the same pop up box on press on touch screen devices.

Comment: I wouldn't mind, but nothing I do (change to :active, :focus, change span to div) can even make the tool tip appear on any of my iOS devices, tapping on it does nothing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there is a way.

First: add the attribute "ontouchstart" to your button.
Second: add a style for :active, :focus, and :hover.

I have tested this on iOS and it works.  (Haven't tried it out with Android).

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
  
}
button:active,
button:focus,
button: hover {
  background-color: blue;
}
button:active + div,
button:focus + div,
button:hover + div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<button ontouchstart>Activate</button>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, ipsa, officiis! Est voluptatibus explicabo sed atque provident vel deleniti nulla quis, ipsa quas dolorum, dolorem cum possimus accusamus impedit nostrum!</div>
<p>Goodbye</p>
```

Comment: Works on Android as well!

Comment: Hi @haltersweb just trying to translate that into my code - as I don't have a button, and there is a floating tooltip instead - in my record is "button" going to be my tooltip title? Can I add `ontouchstart` to a span?

Comment: Ok i've re-written my original code to implement this, and apart from the styling of the tooltip on mobile devices that i'm struggling with (see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159636/making-tooltips-float-and-fill-bottom-half-of-screen-on-mobile) it works. The only issue i've got is that now on desktop you can highlight the desk in the tooltip box or hover over it as it disappears as soon as you mouse away, before you could hover the link then mouse over the box to keep it active. There must be a tweak to enable that?

Comment: I've got the hybrid of yours and @Shaggy answer working. Basically a little bit of minor tweaking to the original code and adding "ontouchstart" seems to have done the trick - now the tooltips pop up and clear on iOS and you can also interact with them on both.
Now all I need to do is figure out how to style the tooltip to fill the screen on mobile

Comment: @DannyShepherd.  Sorry, only just saw this.  You should use a button tag, not a span.  Spans won't be able to be triggered by someone who is blind.  

But just normalize your button styles and make sure to use the attribute type="button" in the tag and you will be fine.  The following styles will strip your button of all styles (it will look like regular text) and then you can add in your own:

    border: none;
    color: #000;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be to add the `tabindex` attribute to your `.tiptext` elements, giving it a value of `-1`. This will allow the elements to receive focus and, therefore, be selectable with the `:focus` pseudo-class.

You'll also need to add the `touchstart` event to your `body` tag (or any parent element of the elements you're working with) in order to get iOS to recognise the `:active` and `:focus` pseudo-classes.

```
<body ontouchstart>
```

```css
.tiptext {
  cursor: help;
  color: black;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600 !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -5px 0 #ebebeb;
  -webkit-transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33, .66, .66, 1);
  transition: background .15s cubic-bezier(.33, .66, .66, 1);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 172%;
  -webkit-animation-name: link-helpoff;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: link-helpoff;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}
.tiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: transparent;
  transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
}
.tiptext:focus::after,.tiptext:hover::after {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
.description {
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 275px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'ProximaNova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgb(39, 44, 45);
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 500;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tiptext > .description {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.4s, opacity 0.4s linear;
}
.tiptext:focus > .description,.tiptext:hover > .description {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease-in;
}
.tiptext:focus,.tiptext:hover {
  color: black;
  -webkit-animation-name: link-help;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: link-help;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<span class="tiptext" tabindex="-1">
  <span class="description" style="text-align:center;">You can read more about the topic in this pop up box</span>
  Mouse over me to learn more.
</span>
```

Comment: I thought this might have cracked it but on iOS the span still does nothing when you press on it. I think my original code and layout need moving around for this to work - or it might have to be have a blank `href` in it to do anything on mobile devices.

Comment: Try setting the `tabindex` to `0` and/or using the `:active` pseudo-class instead of `:focus` to see if it works. Note, though, that setting the `tabindex` to `0` will force your `.tiptext` elements to be the first ones focussed when traversing the page with the TAB key.

Comment: Adding "ontouchstart" from @haltersweb seems to have done the trick - just stuck on styling these boxes for mobile now.

Comment: So the solution was to apply the changes in both our answers, is that correct?

Comment: Indeed, although i'm not sure what "ontouchstart" does but i've only needed to add it to one div and everything on the page works.