Tooltip on touch screen isn't working well when using ggiraph in R
We have created a shiny app https://ficlima.shinyapps.io/mace/ where we use ggiraph to show values on maps and bar charts. It works fine if you use the mouse, but I am wondering how to get it improved when I use a tablet with touch screen. Is there any solution?
I would expect to see the tooltip using touch click or mouse over.

yes, ggiraph does not condition interactivity with the devices. Tooltip or animation is displayed on hover, I guess a tablet does not behave the same than a computer browser

I just found this; I am not sure if something like this would be a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148225/can-my-tooltips-be-adapted-for-touch-screen
